# React native not rerendering after state change until user input

Tags: reactjs, react-native, state, react-animated

My component isnt rerendering until after the user presses a button. I have the user hit a button which animates a change to the position/width of a component, then in the callback I am doing a state change. I was hoping that the re-render would occur after the animation, but it is happening before the next user input. I was wondering how to get the component to rerender immediately once the animation completes?

video: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pmxpc.jpg

```
import React, {useEffect, useRef, useState} from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Button, Animated } from 'react-native';
import GalleryRow from './GalleryRow'

const ImageScreen = () => {

  const [currentRow, setCurrentRow] = useState(0)

  const thirdRowTopValue = new Animated.Value(0)
  const secondRowTopValue = new Animated.Value(10)
  const firstRowTopValue = new Animated.Value(20)
  const frontRowTopValue = new Animated.Value(90)

  const thirdRowWidthValue = new Animated.Value(50)
  const secondRowWidthValue = new Animated.Value(70)
  const firstRowWidthValue = new Animated.Value(100)
  const frontRowWidthValue = new Animated.Value(80)

  const inputRange = [0, 100];
  const outputRange = ["0%", "100%"]

  const thirdRowanimatedTop = thirdRowTopValue.interpolate({inputRange, outputRange});
  const secondRowanimatedTop = secondRowTopValue.interpolate({inputRange, outputRange});
  const firstRowanimatedTop = firstRowTopValue.interpolate({inputRange, outputRange});
  const frontRowanimatedTop = frontRowTopValue.interpolate({inputRange, outputRange});

  const thirdRowanimatedWidth = thirdRowWidthValue.interpolate({inputRange, outputRange});
  const secondRowanimatedWidth = secondRowWidthValue.interpolate({inputRange, outputRange});
  const firstRowanimatedWidth = firstRowWidthValue.interpolate({inputRange, outputRange});
  const frontRowanimatedWidth = frontRowWidthValue.interpolate({inputRange, outputRange});

  function moveForward() {
    Animated.parallel([
      Animated.timing(thirdRowTopValue, {
        toValue: 10,
        duration: 300,
        useNativeDriver: false
      }),
      Animated.timing(secondRowTopValue, {
        toValue: 20,
        duration: 300,
        useNativeDriver: false
      }),
      Animated.timing(firstRowTopValue, {
        toValue: 90,
        duration: 300,
        useNativeDriver: false
      }),
      Animated.timing(frontRowTopValue, {
        toValue: 100,
        duration: 300,
        useNativeDriver: false
      }),
      Animated.timing(thirdRowWidthValue, {
        toValue: 70,
        duration: 300,
        useNativeDriver: false
      }),
      Animated.timing(secondRowWidthValue, {
        toValue: 100,
        duration: 300,
        useNativeDriver: false
      }),
      Animated.timing(firstRowWidthValue, {
        toValue: 80,
        duration: 300,
        useNativeDriver: false
      }),
      Animated.timing(frontRowWidthValue, {
        toValue: 30,
        duration: 300,
        useNativeDriver: false
      }),
    ]).start()
    setTimeout(()=> {
      setCurrentRow(currentRow => currentRow + 1)
    }, 300)
  }

  }

  function moveBackward() {
    Animated.parallel([
      Animated.timing(thirdRowTopValue, {
        toValue: -20,
        useNativeDriver: false
      }),
      Animated.timing(secondRowTopValue, {
        toValue: 0,
        useNativeDriver: false
      }),
      Animated.timing(firstRowTopValue, {
        toValue: 10,
        useNativeDriver: false
      }),
      Animated.timing(frontRowTopValue, {
        toValue: 20,
        useNativeDriver: false
      }),
      //
      Animated.timing(thirdRowWidthValue, {
        toValue: 30,
        useNativeDriver: false
      }),
      Animated.timing(secondRowWidthValue, {
        toValue: 50,
        useNativeDriver: false
      }),
      Animated.timing(firstRowWidthValue, {
        toValue: 70,
        useNativeDriver: false
      }),
      Animated.timing(frontRowWidthValue, {
        toValue: 100,
        useNativeDriver: false
      }),
    ]).start(() => {
      setCurrentRow(currentRow - 1)
    })
  }



  return <View style={styles.page}>
  <View style={styles.parentStyle}>
  <Animated.View style={[styles.thirdRow, {top: thirdRowanimatedTop, width: thirdRowanimatedWidth}]}>
    <GalleryRow images={[
      require('../images/image1.png'),
      require('../images/image2.png'),
      require('../images/image3.png'),
    ]}/>
  </Animated.View>
  <Animated.View style={[styles.secondRow, {top: secondRowanimatedTop, width: secondRowanimatedWidth}]}>
  <GalleryRow images={[
    require('../images/image4.png'),
    require('../images/image5.png'),
    require('../images/image6.png'),
  ]}/>
  </Animated.View>
  <Animated.View style={[styles.firstRow, {top: firstRowanimatedTop, width: firstRowanimatedWidth}]}>
  <GalleryRow images={[
    require('../images/image7.png'),
    require('../images/image8.png'),
    require('../images/image9.png'),
  ]}/>
  </Animated.View>
  <Animated.View style={[styles.frontRow, {top: frontRowanimatedTop, width: frontRowanimatedWidth}]}>
  <GalleryRow images={[
    require('../images/image10.png'),
    require('../images/image11.png'),
    require('../images/image12.png'),
  ]}/>
  </Animated.View>
  </View>
  <View style={styles.button}>
    <Button title="Forward" onPress={moveForward}/>
  </View>
  <View style={styles.button}>
    <Button title="Backward" onPress={moveBackward}/>
  </View>

  </View>;
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  page: {
    height: 800
  },
  parentStyle: {
    borderWidth: 5,
    borderColor: 'black',
    height: 300,
    overflow: 'hidden'
  },
  frontRow: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top:'90%',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    width: '80%',
  },
  firstRow: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top:'20%',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    width: '100%',
  },
  secondRow: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top:'10%',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    width: '70%',
  },
  thirdRow: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top:0,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    width: '50%',
  },
  button: {
    padding: 50
  }
});

export default ImageScreen;


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pmxpc.jpg
```

Comment: by callback, do you mean the ```start()``` method? if yes, it isn't going to do anything after the animation is complete, its the fist script that runs before animation as the name suggests. It will trigger the animations to start, so you have to manually add the end callback once the animations are complete

Comment: @AppyMango i have tried instead using a setTimeout with a duration of the same length of the animation, but i get the same result.

Comment: Can you update your question with the latest code you tried?

Comment: I was trying your issue with the working example in Code Sandbox => https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-benz-o5zvu0?file=/src/App.js

But what exactly are you trying to achieve in the re-render ?

Comment: @AppyMango I am trying to simulate "scrolling" through the z-index. I have the proper animation for every row to move forward, but i then want all of my values to reset except for what imageIndex I am at. Theoretically, everything moved forward and all of the imageViews have replaced the spot in front of them, I add one row to the back, and now everything looks exactly how it started except there are new images => now i can do the animation again. What I am finding is once the animation completes, i don't see a reset, but once i try the animation again the rerender occurs immediately before

Comment: @AppyMango Your sandbox is doing the same thing... i basically am wondering what i can do to have that top row reappear/rerender after moving instead of immediately before the next move

Comment: @AppyMango i updated the code to using settimeout instead of using the callback of the start method (even though documentation says the callback of the start button happens AFTER the animations are complete which is what i want). Why doesnt the rerender happen until the button is clicked again?